# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 on Alexnet

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Hei, I got an error when running code for Alexnet feature extraction. I create`alexnet.pb` file using this github [link](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-workshop/blob/master/08%20Create%20Base%20AlexNet.ipynb). I checked using Tensorboard and the graph went well.

I want to use this model to extract feature from `fc7/relu` and feed it to another model. I create the graph using this:

```
data = 0

model_dir = 'model'
images_dir = 'images_alexnet/train/' + str(data) + '/'
list_images = [images_dir+f for f in os.listdir(images_dir) if re.search('jpeg|JPEG', f)]
list_images.sort()

def create_graph():
    with gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(model_dir, 'alexnet.pb'), 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

create_graph()
```

And then feed the `input` and extract the `fc7/relu` layer using this:

```
def extract_features(image_paths, verbose=False):        
    feature_dimension = 4096
    features = np.empty((len(image_paths), feature_dimension))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        flattened_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('fc7/relu:0')

        for i, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
            if verbose:
                print('Processing %s...' % (image_path))

            if not gfile.Exists(image_path):
                tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)

            image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
            feature = sess.run(flattened_tensor, {'input:0': image_data})
            features[i, :] = np.squeeze(feature)

    return features
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\
```

It seems I did wrong when feeding the graph. I see the graph using Tensorboard and it seems the placeholder `dtype` is `uint8`. How can I solve this?

Full error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Hermon Jay/Documents/Python/diabetic_retinopathy_temp6_transfer_learning/feature_extraction_alexnet.py", line 49, in <module>
    features = extract_features(list_images)

  File "C:/Users/Hermon Jay/Documents/Python/diabetic_retinopathy_temp6_transfer_learning/feature_extraction_alexnet.py", line 44, in extract_features
    feature = sess.run(flattened_tensor, {'input:0': image_data})

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1089, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\
```

Comment: What is the line in your code that raises the error? How did you obtain `alexnet.pb`?

Comment: @jdehesa I get it using this https://github.com/HermonJay/diabetic_retinopathy/blob/master/Create%20Alexnet.ipynb and the error goes to this line `feature = sess.run(flattened_tensor, {'input:0': image_data})`

Comment: And the line producing the error?

Comment: @jdehesa done editted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

Is reading the file at `image_path` as an array of bytes. However, what the `input` placeholder expects is a four-dimensional array of type `uint8`. Take a look, for example, at one of the next tutorials from the link you provided, [10 AlexNet Transfer Learning](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-workshop/blob/master/10%20AlexNet%20Transfer%20Learning.ipynb); the function `get_batch` produces the batches using an additional graph an operations like [`tf.image.decode_jpeg`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg); then it gives the result of that graph as input to the main network graph.

For example, you could have something like this (if all your images fit in memory, otherwise you'd have to batch them like in the tutorial):

```
def read_images(image_paths):
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
        file_name = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        jpeg_data = tf.read_file(jpeg_name)
        decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpeg_data, channels=3)
        images = []
        for path in image_paths:
            images.append(sess.run(decoded_image, feed_dict={file_name: path}))
        return images

def extract_features(image_paths):
    images = read_images(image_paths)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        flattened_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('fc7/relu:0')
        return sess.run(flattened_tensor, {'input:0': images})
```